# Reload UITableView row after downloading image (using MVVM)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

In application I am writing I decided to use MVVM patter. I am binding ViewModels with Views using RxSwift + RxCocoa. Now I am facing a problem I cannot find any solution myself.

I have a list of ViewModels which I want to display in UITableView. In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method I am dequeueing a cell and I am binding one of ViewModels from the list to this cell. ViewModel has `imageUrl` Variable and I use Kingfisher to download this image and put it into ImageView in that cell.

So here is my problem now: when download is completed I have to reload this row so Auto Layout will calculate its correct height. But when I use `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)` the binding is recreated and it ends up with infinite loop (binding -> image download completion callback -> reload row -> binding -> ...)!

Any ideas how to workaround this?

Comment: Share the code please!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reload the row for autolayout to calculate the height (actually, never do that).
Configure your tableview to have adaptative height and you're done.

You can find a good example of this on https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: Hi. Sadly this is not true. When row with image is displayed and image is downloaded nothing happens. I have to scroll this row off the screen and scroll it in again - then image is correctly displayed.

Comment: @Tiero it is true, i have a huge project with a collectionview displaying images for all items and we never reload the row.
If the image doesn't display it means your code is incorrect.

Comment: So how do you constrain your ImageView to make it work?

Comment: You didn't design your cells?

Comment: Simple example: ImageView inside UITableViewCell. From now iv = ImageView, con = ContentView of that cell. I constrain iv.leadin = con.leading, iv.trailing = con.trailing, iv.top = con.top, iv.bottom = con.bottom. So basicly ImageView covers whole cell. I want cell height to adapt to ImageView's height. When image is downloaded while cell is being displayed nothing happens.  I have to scroll up/down and then down/up again for it to appear.

Comment: And that is because your code is incorrect.
Autolayout and adaptative height, read tutorials on that and you will get there.